# Is it possible to generate reports with dynamic columns in OpenERP?

Tags: python, report, odoo

I need to understand if it is possible to create reports with `X` number of columns. `X` will come from the amenities a hotel have for example. So it will change depending on the hotel selected from a wizard before generating the report.

Lets say Hotel XYZ has 5 amenities I need a report with 5 columns where I will show the payments each guest made for each amenity. Then Hotel YYY will have 10 amenities and I need to do the same but for all 10 amenities.

Will it be possible to code a report (I am currently using the OpenOffice plugin but anything that work would be fine) flexible enough to do this with OpenERP?

I am not asking how to do it, I just want to understand the possibilities and limitations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can delete table cells when a certain condition is met using the removeParentNode rml directive:

```
[[ function_performing_check_on_condition(object) and removeParentNode('td')]]
```

You can also dynamically resize the columns using the setTag directive within the <blockTable> section:

```
[[ setTag('blockTable','blockTable', {'colWidths': get_column_widths(obj)}) ]]
```

However, I believe there is a bug in OpenERP when you apply the setTag. Namely, the text after the table is just not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use webkit reporting. Any other openerp reporting tools have its limitations for creating dynamic columns.

Comment: With webkit it will be possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it will, webkit uses Mako as a templating engine so between that and the parser you should be able to do pretty much whatever you want.